# How to achieve Typewriter effect in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I'd like to print a longer text **letter by letter** - as if someone is just typing it on a typewriter. What's the best approach here in **JavaFX**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to take a string and then lay it out letter-by-letter on to the scene to simulate a typewriter typing.
Iterate over the string and maybe increment an x,y position of the current letter to get it in place on the screen.
Take a look at the TimeLine object in the [JavaFX 1.3 api](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1.3/docs/api/), at each "tick" of the timeline you can write a new letter out.
A small random delay will make the layout appear more like typing (look at PauseTransition - which executes an action after a given delay - this could be bound to a var set randomly at each tick).

Hope this helps. Feel free to post it back here or to somewhere like [jfxstudio.org](http://jfxstudio.org) when you get it working.